# FTP guaranteed file delivery for Android

Tags: android, ftp, apache-commons, apache-commons-net

I'm using Apache commons Net library for FTP in my android app. and sometimes when using interrupted network or 2G network it doesn't send/download the file as expected.

I know that i have to check the boolean result of storeFile function in order to resend the file again and again...and sometime it sends corrupted files.

is there a library that uses Apache commons net library but it guarantees file sync process (including resuming, checking if the delivered file has the same size as the one in the client/server). is there any sync library that take care of all these checks for me.
the sync process doesn't have to be immediately. but with 100% guaranteed file delivery.

this issue does not happen when using WIFI.